# How to reduce the font size automatically based on line count

Tags: titles

Now, the default title font size is 17 points. But I will try to reduce the font size automatically if the title lines exceeds more than three lines.

My need is `\titlefont` command is working automatically  more than three lines. Otherwise, the default title font size should be followed. Now, i am given manually in `\title` command.

Please advise how to implement the logic through the `LaTeX` Macros.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\date{}

\def\titlefont{\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\title{\titlefont Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size: Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size:Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size:Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the example you've given, the font size would have to be reduced all the way to `11pt` to make the title fit in three lines. Many readers might not even recognize such a three-line construct as the title of the document. Rather than fiddle with the appearance of the long title, are you in a position to *shorten* the title? Your readers might appreciate it quite a bit. Who, after all, can correctly remember the title of the publication if the title spans three full lines? Or, do you maybe want your publication to be remembered by some readers as "the piece with the incredibly long title"?

Comment: Mico's advice is good. In any case: I looked at this with my limited TeX skills, and concluded that it is not easily possible to automate the font size, without 2 compilations (perhaps using `zref`). The reason is that the layout of the title text is not known until page shipout, when it is too late to change it. So, since you have to compile twice, it is simpler to manually change the size by visual inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthough I agree with Mico regarding the length of the title, here is a solution for your problem.

It uses normal font size commands (`\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, and `\huge`) to avoid font substitution, which happens in your example. This can easily be changed (see comment in code). If you use scalable fonts (e.g. latin modern), you can set any size without having this problem.

Here instead of `\title` the new command `\autotitle` is used. It has an optional argument giving the number of lines to scale to (default is 3). If with the smallest font (`\large`) the number of lines can't be reached, a warning is given out.

It works by setting the title in a box to get the height, which is then compared to the `\baselineskip` of the font size used. If there are too many lines, this is repeated for the next smaller font size. If the smallest is reached, this is used and a warning is given out.

If you want to use different formatting for the title, e.g. `\bfseries`, this has to be added to `\test@lines` (see comment in code for exact position).

```
\documentclass{article}

\date{2017-11-28}
\author{Me}

% there is no 15pt font in the cm fonts, so it is substituted (stated in the log file)
%\def\titlefont{\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\newbox\test@box
\newdimen\test@blskip
\newcommand*{\test@lines}[1]{%
    \setbox\test@box\hbox to\textwidth{\vbox{\centering\test@fontsize #1\global\test@blskip\baselineskip\par}}%
    % add formating commands for the title here ---------------------^
}
\newcommand*{\autotitle}[2][3]{%
% \huge
    \let\test@fontsize\huge\test@lines{#2}%
    % or you can write
    %\def\test@fontsize{\fontsize{20.74}{25}\selectfont}\test@lines{#2}%
    \ifdim\ht\test@box>#1\test@blskip
% \LARGE
        \let\test@fontsize\LARGE\test@lines{#2}%
        \ifdim\ht\test@box>#1\test@blskip
% \Large
            \let\test@fontsize\Large\test@lines{#2}%
            \ifdim\ht\test@box>#1\test@blskip
% \large
                \let\test@fontsize\large\test@lines{#2}%
                \ifdim\ht\test@box>#1\test@blskip
                    \PackageWarning{preamble}{could not reduce title to three lines (using \string\large\space for title).}
                \else
                    \PackageInfo{preamble}{using \string\large\space for title}%
                \fi
% \Large
            \else
                \PackageInfo{preamble}{using \string\Large\space for title}%
            \fi
% \LARGE
        \else
            \PackageInfo{preamble}{using \string\LARGE\space for title}%
        \fi
% \huge
    \else
        \PackageInfo{preamble}{using \string\huge\space for title}%
    \fi
% always
    \title{\test@fontsize #2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\autotitle{Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size:
Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size:
Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size:
Sample text exceed three lines reduce the font size%
}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun: this attempts typesetting the title starting at 11pt and stepping 1pt each time, until the length of the title exceeds three lines.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % if you don't use a scalable font

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\TITLE}[1]{%
  \count@=10
  \loop
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \fontsize{\count@}{0}\selectfont
    \centering #1\par
    \xdef\vetri@len{\the\prevgraf}
  }%
  \ifnum\vetri@len<4
  \repeat
  \advance\count@\m@ne
  \ifnum\count@>17 \count@=17 \fi % maximum size is 17pt
  \title{\fontsize{\count@}{1.2\dimexpr\count@ pt}\selectfont #1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{Me}

\TITLE{Sample text exceeds three lines reduce the font size:
  Sample text exceeds three lines reduce the font size:
  Sample text exceeds three lines reduce the font size and stop}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example the chosen size is 13pt and you can check that

```
\begin{center}\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont
Sample text exceeds three lines reduce the font size:
Sample text exceeds three lines reduce the font size:
Sample text exceeds three lines reduce the font size and stop
\end{center}
```

takes four lines.